# If a $p$-adic formal power series $\Phi(T)$ satisfies $\Phi(\zeta-1)\in\mu_{p^\infty}$, then $\Phi(T)=\zeta_0(T+1)^b$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, roots-of-unity

Let $\mathbb Z_p$ denote the set of $p$-adic intergers and $\mathbb Q_p$ the set of $p$-adic numbers. Write $\mu_{p^\infty}:=\{\zeta\in\overline{\mathbb Q}_p\mid \zeta^{p^n}=1\text{ for some }n\geqslant 0\}$. For $\Phi(T)\in\mathbb Z_p[[T]]$, I am stuck in proving the following

> **Problem.** If there is some infinite subset $\Sigma\subseteq\mu_{p^\infty}$ such that $\Phi(\zeta-1)\in\mu_{p^\infty}$ for all $\zeta\in\Sigma$, then $\Phi(T)=\zeta_0(T+1)^b$ for some $\zeta_0\in\mu_{p^\infty}$ and $b\in\mathbb Z_p$.

Let's fix a $\zeta'\in\Sigma$. If we define a new power series $\Psi'(T)=\Phi(\zeta'(T+1)-1)$, then $\Psi'(0)=\Phi(\zeta'-1)\in\mu_{p^\infty}$. We define $\zeta_0':=\Phi(\zeta'-1)$, $\zeta_0:=\zeta_0'\zeta'^{-1}$ and $\Psi(T):=\Psi'(T)/\zeta_0\in\mathbb Z_p[[T]]$. The power series $\Psi(T)$ satisfies $\Psi(0)=1$ and if $\Psi(T)=(T+1)^b$, then $\Psi'(T)=\zeta_0'(T+1)^b$ and thus $\Phi(T)=\zeta_0(T+1)^b$. Hence the case is reduced as in the title, i.e. we may assume that $\Phi(0)=1$ and it remains to show that $\Phi(T)=(T+1)^b$ for some $b\in\mathbb Z_p$. This is where I am stuck, as I cannot see how it can be proved that the coefficients of $\Phi$ are exactly the binomial coefficients.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: In the statement of your problem you can take $\Sigma = \{1\}$, so a special case of your problem is: if $\Phi(T) \in \mathbf Z_p[[T]]$ satisfies $\Phi(0) = 1$ then $\Phi(T) = (1+T)^b$ for some $b\in \mathbf Z_p$, and that is not true.

Comment: Your question has several problems. Can you prove that $\Phi(\zeta_{p^{n_j}}-1)=\zeta_0 \zeta_{p^{n_j}}^{b_j}$ where $b_j\equiv b_{j+1}\bmod p^{n_j}$ ?

Comment: @KCd You are right. The statement has some problem. The subset $\Sigma$ is supposed to be an infinite subet...

Comment: @reuns Do you mean $\Phi(\zeta_{p^n}-1)=\zeta_0\zeta_{p^n}^{b_n}$? What I can imagine for now is that since $\Phi(\zeta_{p^n}-1)\in\mu_{p^\infty}$ , we can assume $\Phi(\zeta_{p^n}-1)^{p^{a_n}}=1$ for some $a_n$. Then by either adding or subtracting a suitable number to $a_n$ we may split $p^{a_n}=p^nb_n$. Hence $\Phi(\zeta_{p^n}-1)=\zeta_{p^n}^{b_n}$...

Answer (score 3):

For $p$ odd then $\zeta_0=1$. We are told that $\Phi(\zeta_{p^{n_j}}-1)=\zeta_{p^{m_j}}^{a_j}$ for a strictly increasing sequence $n_j$. Since $|\phi(\zeta_{p^{n_j}}-1)-1|\le |\zeta_{p^{n_j}}-1|$ we get $m_j\ge n_j$ and $\Phi(\zeta_{p^{n_j}}-1)=\zeta_{p^{n_j}}^{b_j}$.

Since $\overline{\Bbb{Z}_p}/(p)$ is a commutative ring of characteristic $p$ we have $(u+v)^p=u^p+v^p\bmod p$ which means that

$$\Phi(\zeta_{p^{n_j}}^{p^k}-1)\equiv \Phi(\zeta_{p^{n_j}}-1)^{p^k}\bmod p$$ Therefore $\zeta_{p^{n_j}}^{b_j}\equiv \zeta_{p^{n_{j+1}}}^{b_{j+1} p^{n_{j+1}-n_j}}\bmod p$ which implies that $ b_{j+1}\equiv b_j\bmod p^{n_j}$. Whence $$\Phi(\zeta_{p^{n_j}}-1)= \zeta_{p^{n_j}}^b $$ where $b=\lim_{j\to \infty} b_j\in \Bbb{Z}_p$.

I don't know if it is what you want to prove or if you expect something stronger.

Comment: What is $\overline{\mathbf Z_p}$?  If that's the integral closure of $\mathbf Z_p$ in the algebraic closure of $\mathbf Q_p$, the ideal $(p)$ in $\overline{\mathbf Z_p}$ is definitely not a prime ideal (think of $p$ having square roots, cube roots, and so on), so the *ring* $\overline{\mathbf Z_p}/(p)$ has characteristic $p$ but it is not an integral domain. Still, you have $(u+v)^p = u^p + v^p$ in that ring because it has characteristic $p$ whether or not it is an integral domain.

Comment: Sure, it is a typo I meant commutative ring not integral domain, tks

Comment: @KCd Did you see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536787/polynomials-with-unit-discriminant) question

Comment: No.  Is there some connection between that question and the one on this page?

Comment: No, it is just that it is above my level and you are one of the specialist

Comment: Okay, I posted an answer there.

Comment: This is nice. It took me a while, here in my dotage, to understand the logic of your argument, but far as I can see, it’s sound. Thanks for this.