# Polynomials with Unit Discriminant

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_1x+a_0\in \mathbb{C}[x]$ be a monic polynomial with algebraic integer coefficients and $n>1$. Let $K$ be the number field $\mathbb{Q}(a_{n-1},\dots,a_0)$. Suppose that the discriminant of $f$, denoted $D(f)$, is a unit in $K$. In other words, $D(f)\in \mathcal{O}_K^*$, where $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the ring of integers of $K$. Is it possible for such an $f$ to be irreducible over $K$?

When $K=\mathbb{Q}$ this is not possible. I'm used to thinking about things over number fields, but I'm happy to hear about answers in different settings.

Comment: [It](https://sci-hub.tw/https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869300984679) says it is a theorem of Artin that $L/K$ cyclic of prime degree unramified at every finite prime would be monogenic $O_L = O_K[a]\cong O_K[x]/(f)$. This implies that the prime ideals $(\mathfrak{p},f_j(x))$ are all different (where $f_j$ ranges over the irreducible factors of $f\in O_K/\mathfrak{p}[x]$) thus $f\in O_K/\mathfrak{p}[x]$ has no repeated root, $Disc(f)\not \in \mathfrak{p}$, since it is true for all $\mathfrak{p}$ it means $Disc(f) \in O_K^\times$.

Comment: @reuns your link to the paper mentioning Artin's theorem says $O_L = O_K[a]$ for cyclic unramified (at finite places) $L/K$ of prime degree when the degree is an *odd* prime. In the case of quadratic unramified (at finite places) $L/K$, the conclusion $O_L = O_K[a]$ is based on the additional hypothesis that $L = K(\sqrt{u})$ for $u \in O_K^\times$.

Comment: @KCd Tks. As I said this is above my level, but I noticed there are several elementary properties in the relation between finite place unramified and monogenic, how it behaves with respect to subextensions, the algorithm to find the monogenic generator. I don't think I [ever saw](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=unramified+monogenic) this idea in the question feed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $K$ be a real quadratic field and $u$ be a fundamental unit of $\mathcal O_K$.  Then $\sqrt{u} \not\in K$, so the field 
$K(\sqrt{u}) = K((1+\sqrt{u})/2)$ is a quadratic extension of $K$ and the minimal polynomial of $(1+\sqrt{u})/2$ over $K$ is 
$$
\left(x - \frac{1+\sqrt{u}}{2}\right)\left(x - \frac{1-\sqrt{u}}{2}\right) = 
x^2 - x + \frac{1-u}{4}, 
$$
so this is irreducible over $K$. 
We want this to have algebraic integer coefficients, so we need $u \equiv 1 \bmod 4\mathcal O_K$.  Assuming we can find such an example, this fits your desired conclusion since the discriminant of $x^2 - x + (1-u)/4$ is $u$.

To find examples of this, write $K = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{d})$ where $d$ is a squarefree integer. Then $\mathcal O_K$ has $\mathbf Z$-basis $\{1,\omega\}$,  where $\omega = \sqrt{d}$ if $d \not\equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and $\omega = (1+\sqrt{d})/2$ if $d \equiv 1 \bmod 4$. Writing $u = a + b\omega$ for integers $a$ and $b$, the constraint $u \equiv 1 \bmod 4\mathcal O_K$ is the same as $a \equiv 1 \bmod 4\mathbf Z$ and $b \equiv 0 \bmod 4\mathbf Z$. Searching through the table of real quadratic fields and their fundamental  units at the back of Borevich and Shafarevich's "Number Theory" (Table 1 on p. 422), three real quadratic fields where the fundamental unit is $1 \bmod 4\mathcal O_K$ are 
$$
\mathbf Q(\sqrt{39}), \ \ u = 25 + 4\sqrt{39},
$$
$$
\mathbf Q(\sqrt{55}), \ \ u = 89 + 12\sqrt{55},
$$
$$
\mathbf Q(\sqrt{66}), \ \ u = 65 + 8\sqrt{66}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

The quadratic $x^2 + \sqrt{3} x + 1$ has discriminant $(\sqrt{3})^2  - 4 = -1$. On the other hand, this is certainly irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, since it has roots

$$\frac{-\sqrt{3} \pm \sqrt{-1}}{2},$$

and $\sqrt{-1} \not\in \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ (it is imaginary, for example).